# Touch Scroll bar in App Windows not working in tablet mode

Tags: css, angular, cordova, jquery-plugins, ionic2

I have a problem with a scrollbar inserted through `Ionic 2+` Framework.

I want to deploy a app in Windows 10. I have introduced `ion-scroll` and all is working. My issue is: When I change to "Tablet mode" and disconnect the mouse and keyboard,where I only can use the touch screen, then the scrollbar inserted is replaced by another scroll, more thinner and I can´t interact with that. I can´t swipe the scrollbar.

I´ve tried to solve the problema with jquery, where I have used jscrollpane, also I have implemented this with CSS (overflow) and Ionic 2+ framework as I have said before.

Comment: thanks for the corrections. Have you any solution for my question, @Sangwin Gawande?. I'm blocked

Comment: What have you used so far? Can you post more details